# Trouble changing Box Shadow of Muse containing rectangle from Edge Animate animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-edge

I am having trouble getting the containing rectangle created in Muse to change it's box shadow onMousover of an Edge animation.

I have found the ID of the containing rectangle and I am trying to access it through the mouseover code of the animation stage.  I have tried a few methods but without success.  I would expect either of these methods to work: -

```
 var thisElement = parent.document.getElementById("u8584");
 thisElement.css({ boxShadow: '0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)' })
```

or

```
 parent.document.getElementById("u8584").css({ boxShadow: '0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)' })
```

any ideas?

Comment: wat is parent.document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`css` is a method of JQuery object, DOM Element objects don't have `css` method. For using `css` you should create a jQuery object.

```
$(thisElement).css({ boxShadow: '0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)' });
```

Or use `style` property:

```
thisElement.style.boxShadow = '0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b4aLg/

Comment: Oh, Ok... I may be mixing my methods... I'll have another go.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that did it I used this and it worked fine. Thanks:
var thisElement = parent.document.getElementById("u8584");
thisElement.style.boxShadow =  '0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)';